# How can I make an Excel 2010 worksheet read-only without a password?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I want to make one of the worksheets in an Excel 2010 workbook read-only, but I don't want to use a password. I just want to make it so that I can't accidentally edit the sheet, and I don't want to have to deal with a password--not even a blank one. In essence, I want to do the same thing as setting the read-only bit for a file, but I want to do it for an Excel 2010 worksheet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What's your goal here?

---

**Remind yourself that you don't want to edit this sheet**

If it's to prevent *yourself* from accidentally editing the sheet, one solution is to draw giant rectangle that covers all your data and set it's transparency to 100%. This will allow you to see everything but prevent you from clicking on any of the cells. However, it would still be possible to use the keyboard to navigate around and edit the cells under the shapes. This idea serves mostly as a reminder since it's easy to simply delete the shape and use the sheet normally. It's not very robust and it's annoying to apply but quick to remove.

---

**Make it impossible to edit the sheet until you click a specific button**

You've already stated that protecting the sheet with a blank password is not the approach you want but it's certainly the simplest. I'm curious why you don't like it. There are a few annoyance like having to deal with a dialog box when you turn it on and dealing with a popup box whenever you try to edit a cell.

You could write some VBA to automatically protect and unprotect the sheet with a blank password. It would be easy enough to use but you'd have to put a button on your toolbar somewhere to call that macro. The popup boxes when you try to edit a cell will still occur. I.E., it doesn't save you very much time. I would recommend, though, *not* checking all the boxes when you protect it because doing so would allow you to add / delete rows & columns - among other things - which you probably don't want to do.

**EDIT:** (based on OP's comment)

Here's the VBA to toggle sheet protection. You can use this to make a single button that turns it on and off. [This article](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Assign-a-macro-to-a-button-728c83ec-61d0-40bd-b6ba-927f84eb5d2c) can offer all the details of how to add custom macros to the ribbon or quick-access toolbar. In brief, though: Right-click in an open space on the ribbon and click "Customize the Quick Access Toolbar" or "Customize the Ribbon" to open a new window. Set drop-down in the top left labeled "Choose commands from:" to be "Macros" and then find the macro in the list. Once you add it, you can edit the icon and name.

```
Sub ToggleSheetProtection()
    'Enables / Disables sheet protection with a blank password
    'When disabling protection, it will prompt for a password only if it isn't blank
    With ActiveSheet
        If .ProtectContents Then .Unprotect Else .Protect "", True, True, True, True
    End With
End Sub
```

Key Points:

1. As written, it only locks the user interface. This means VBA can still edit the sheet. To change that, drop the last `True` after `.Protect`. (In fact, thanks to default values, you can drop everything on that line after `.Protect`.)
2. You'll still get the popup when you try to edit things.

Comment: My primary objection to the password approach is that I have to remember that it's blank. In a comment above, madamission pointed out that there's no password prompt to unprotect a sheet when the protecting password is blank, and that makes the approach more palatable. But I find Excel's interface in this area confusing. If the UI told me that a password was optional, I'd simply omit it and be on my way. It appears that that's how Excel behaves, which is nice, but the sheet-protection UI offers no hint that the password may be blank and that there's no unprotection prompt for blank passwords.

Comment: @KnowItAllWannabe I added the VBA code and some guidance of how to implement it. It's essentially a single-click to protect / unprotect with a blank password.

Answer (score 2):

To protect just one sheet, right click on the "Sheet1" tab (or the name of the tab you want to protect) and click "Protect sheet."

Select all the desired options in the list and don't set a password, then click OK.  By not setting a password it will not prompt you for a password if you want to unprotect it.

To unprotect it, right click again and select "unprotect"

Comment: This approach unfortunately requires that I have a blank password, but I'm upvoting it due to the useful comment that I have to manually select all the options in the list. Is there really no one-checkbox action that can set a read-only bit for a single worksheet?

Comment: Note that when you leave the password blank it doesn't prompt you for a password when you unprotect, which is what you want.

Comment: If this is something that you want to do regularly and make it a "one-click" option, you could write a macro that does all those steps to protect the sheet.

Comment: I would recommend *not* checking all the boxes when you protect it because doing so would allow you to add / delete rows & columns - among other things - which you probably don't want to do.

Comment: Yes thanks, I've edited to say only select "desired" options.

Comment: @madamission: Thanks for pointing out that there's no password prompt when the password is blank. That eliminates one of the reasons I didn't want to have to deal with a password.

Answer (score 0):

**1** WorkSheet

Right click on tap

[image]

**2** Workbook

*On the Files tab; Save As, Tools, General Options, and passwords can be specified to open or modify.*

[image]

[image]

**3**  *Right-click on the file's icon, select properties, next to attributes click "read only"*

Comment: Downvoted, because the first solution ignores that I don't want to have even a blank password, and the second solution applies to all the sheets in a workbook, not just one.

Comment: The second solution is just extra info to share so others may find helpful